# How to trigger an alert with javascript if a certain image is chosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I am trying to get an alert if I chose a certain picture for example:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
<img id='pr' style="width: 500px;height: 600px;" src="">
</div>
```

Then I manually chose a picture that goes into 'main' and changes it src JQUERY:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#paperb').click(function()
{
$('#pr').attr("src", "http://www.cliparthut.com/clip-arts/1008/paper-stack-
clip-art-1008442.jpg");
});  </script>
```

Than there comes the JS that fails:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (getElementById('#pr').attr('src' ,'https://i.redd.it/2u0y0z5i12py.png') 
{
alert('euirhzeurhzu')
} 
</script>
```

But this script wont work. Is it possible to get an alert from this?
What do I need to change so I can get an alert?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if (getElementById('#pr').attr('src' ,'https://i.redd.it/2u0y0z5i12py.png')
```

with

```
if (getElementById('#pr').attr('src') === 'https://i.redd.it/2u0y0z5i12py.png')
```

Also the other problem is that your `if` statement is not declared in an event handler. So it will run only once when the script first loads. You need to place it under an event after which you want to execute it. E.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('body').on('click','#pr',function(){
      if ($('#pr').attr('src') === 'https://i.redd.it/2u0y0z5i12py.png') {
          alert('euirhzeurhzu');
       }
   });
</script>
```

**Edit**: Here's a working snippet.

```js
   $('body').on('click','#pr',function(){
      if ($('#pr').attr('src') === 'https://i.redd.it/2u0y0z5i12py.png') {
          alert('euirhzeurhzu');
       }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
<img id='pr' style="width: 500px;height: 600px;" src="https://i.redd.it/2u0y0z5i12py.png">
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't work there is one too many ( and even if i remove still doesnt work

Comment: @brotopia So in your click handler, you are setting a different source from the one you are comparing with in your `if` statement.  You need to mention what your intention is. It is unclear.

Comment: what i wanna do is if i chose an image with this same link as the IF statement it needs to trigger the alert

Comment: @brotopia, okay. So what is the elemtn with the id `paperb`?

Comment: paperb is a button i created just an image i click on and then it puts the picture in the main slot

Comment: sorry but how do i i place it under an event after wich i want to execute it? im a beginner ;'(

Comment: I have edited my answer to show an example. See if that works.

Comment: thank you but still doesnt work for some reason,just so you know even if it doesnt work at the end of the day i love you!

Comment: @brotopia, thanks for your love. I have shown a working solution in my answer. See if you can figure out the error in  your JS. (Hint: what is `getElemntById` function that you are using in the `if` statement?)

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple images & want to do some action when src value is changed for certain images, then try below;

```
$('#pr').on('load', function (e) { 
    console.log("Image Path: ", e.target.src); 
    if(e.target.src == "https://i.redd.it/2u0y0z5i12py.png") { 
        //do action a 
    } else if(e.target.src == "https://...bike.png") { 
        //do action b 
    }
});
```

Comment: what i wanna do is if i chose an image with this same link as the IF statement it needs to trigger the alert